# Distribution of time series data in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, kdb

I currently have a kdb+ database with ~1mil rows of financial tick data. Using Python3, TensorFlow, and numpy, what is the best way to break up time-series financial data into train/dev/test sets?

[This paper](https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.28.2.3) suggests the use of k-fold cross-validation, which partitions the data into complimentary subsets. But it's from Spring-2014 and after reading it I'm still unclear on how to implement it in practice. Is this the best solution or is something like hold-out validation more appropriate for financial data?

I'm also interested in learning best practices for importing locally stored time-series data into my TensorFlow model.

Thank you.

Comment: Two very big questions.  They are very good, but I don't think they're suited to a programming Q&A site like SO.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo. Any recommendations on where these questions would be best received or links pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: You may find success on the [kdb personal developers google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/personal-kdbplus)

Comment: @ThomasSmyth I think I'll do that. Although I was hesitant at first since I didn't want a pure Kdb+/q solution to importing the data. But i suppose I could combine it with pyq to make it work in Python.

Answer (score 0):

One can use qPython to load the data to the Python process and then KFold from sklearn to repeatedly split the data set into training and test part.
Suppose we have the following table defined on the KDB+ side:

```
t:([] time:.z.t+til 30;ask:100.0+30?1.0;bid:98+30?1.0)
```

Then on the Python side you can do the following to produce indices of the train/test splits:

```
from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5001, pandas = True) as q:
    X = q.sync('t')

kf = KFold(n_splits=4)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

See the [KFold documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) for other variants of KFold.